Copying data between tables in same SQL Server DB using Python is too slow
I am trying to copy data from one table to another table in the same database through Python. The current speed at which the data is copied is 4.5s per 100 records which is excessive. I have to copy millions of records and at 4.5s per 100 records it would take forever.
Can anyone suggest a better way?
Following is my code
# Establish SQLAlchemy engine
            connection_string = f'mssql+pyodbc://{connection_info[2]}:{connection_info[3]}@{connection_info[0]}/{connection_info[1]}?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server'
            print(connection_string)
            sqlalchemy_engine = create_engine(connection_string, fast_executemany=True)
            if connection_info[1] == 'AxDB':
                with get_sql_server_connection(connection_info) as sql_server_conn:
                    print("Connected to SQL Server database successfully!")

                    # Fetch mapping details
                    mapping_detail_query = """
                    SELECT TableName, MappingName, SourceColumns, "Filter"
                    FROM MappingTable
                    WHERE LocID=3
                    """
                    mapping_detail = execute_sqlite_query(sqlite_conn, mapping_detail_query)[0]

                    tablename, mappingname, sourcecolumns, _filter = mapping_detail

                    # Query SQL Server
                    mapping_query = f"""
                    SELECT {sourcecolumns}
                    FROM {tablename}
                    """
                    chunk_size = 100  # Adjust as needed

                    accumulated_values = []

                    for chunk_df in pd.read_sql_query(mapping_query, sqlalchemy_engine, chunksize=chunk_size):
                        # Prepare INSERT query for SQL Server
                        insert_query = f"""
                        INSERT INTO PRODPARMUPDATE_tst ({sourcecolumns})
                        VALUES ({', '.join(['?' for _ in range(len(sourcecolumns.split(',')))])})
                        """
                        # Accumulate values from the current chunk
                        accumulated_values.extend(chunk_df.values.tolist())

                        # Check if accumulated values reach a certain threshold (e.g., 1000)
                        if len(accumulated_values) >= 200:
                            # Execute `executemany` with the accumulated values
                            cursor = sql_server_conn.cursor()
                            cursor.executemany(insert_query, accumulated_values)
                            sql_server_conn.commit()

                            # Print date and time alongside the message
                            current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                            print(f"Bulk insertion successful! - {current_datetime}")

                            # Clear accumulated values for the next batch
                            accumulated_values = []

Changing the chunk_size is not helping at all.

At first I implemented the logic using a for loop only - which was fetching records one by one of course.
After some research I got to know about the SQLAlchemy and I implemented it but it only optimized the speed a little giving me 4.5sec per 100 records.
I tried implementing the parallel processing method but that is giving me the following error:


Error inserting data: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Following is the code where I've made changes for parallel processing
def insert_chunk(data_chunk):
                    try:
                        # Connect to the database using a new connection
                        conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
                        cursor = conn.cursor()
                        # Prepare INSERT query for SQL Server
                        insert_query = f"""
                        INSERT INTO PRODPARMUPDATE_tst ({sourcecolumns})
                        VALUES ({', '.join(['?' for _ in range(len(sourcecolumns.split(',')))])})
                        """
                        # Execute `executemany` with the data chunk
                        cursor.executemany(insert_query, data_chunk)
                        conn.commit()
                        cursor.close()
                        conn.close()
                        # Print date and time alongside the message
                        current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                        print(f"Bulk insertion successful! - {current_datetime}")
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(f"Error inserting data: {e}")

                # Split your data into chunks
                data_chunks = pd.read_sql_query(mapping_query, sqlalchemy_engine, chunksize=chunk_size)
                data_chunks = [tuple(chunk_df.values.tolist()) for chunk_df in data_chunks]

                # Use ThreadPoolExecutor to insert data chunks in parallel
                with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
                    # Pass connection_string as an argument to each thread
                    executor.map(lambda chunk: insert_chunk(chunk), data_chunks)


Typically to make such a transfer you'd just do it directly in SQL: INSERT INTO PRODPARMUPDATE_tst ({sourcecolumns}) SELECT {sourcecolumns} FROM {tablename}

Please review code indentation. You don't need one for your first level code lines inside triple back ticks. Consider a tag based on keyword [performance]

@Nick Hi, Actually i'm building a product. So this needs to be done through python. I am keeping everything dynamic. Even the connection to database. It connects to different databases based on the Jurisdiction we provide. So is there a way to optimize the speed in python?

@OCa Hi, actually this part of def main() and then there is Try block and with clause etc. hence the indentation is there.

@HiraSadiq there's no reason you can't send that SQL command to the SQL server via python

Copying row-by-row is always going to be slow, and retrieiving the rows to Python only to send them back again is also going to slow things down.
What you are doing is completely ridiculous. You don't need all these loops, and you don't even need to bring the data back to Python in the first place.
Just build a single dynamic INSERT command and execute it.
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT TOP (1)
  @sql = '
INSERT INTO PRODPARMUPDATE_tst (' + SourceColumns + ')
SELECT ' + SourceColumns + '
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(TableName)
FROM MappingTable
WHERE LocID = 3;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

